# How to change PATH priority for specified command in zsh

Tags: path

I installed `vim` by using `brew`, but because `/usr/bin` have higher priority than `/usr/local/bin/` the `/usr/bin/vi` is called by default.

```
which -a vi
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/local/bin/vi
```

I can create a alias in `~/.zshrc`, but I'm using the init file also in other environment that doesn't have `/usr/local/bin/vi`.

If I change the priority of the paths `/usr/bin/` and `/usr/local/bin`, some side effects may happen.

So I want to change the priority of paths only for `vi` command.
How can I do it? Or is there better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd fix the PATH. Yours is an unusual config. Normally `local` paths preceded nonlocal ones and that is the way it should be. If you switch it around, then yes, some stuff may theoretically break, but I'd worry about that when it actually happens. Local paths should have a higher priority than nonlocal ones.

Answer (score 1):

use hash: `hash vi=/usr/local/bin/vi`